# Compiling Qt 5.0 with Visual Studio 2012 (64-bit)

Tags: qt, windows-7, visual-studio-2012, qt5

I try to compile Qt 5.0.1 with Visual Studio 2012 Pro and Windows 7.

I make git clone from source Qt 5.0

I make configure, then nmake in command line dev tool.

But it's linker fault:

```
        echo 1 /* CREATEPROCESS_MANIFEST_RESOURCE_ID */ 24 /* RT_MANIFEST */ "..
\\..\\..\\..\\plugins\\platforms\\qwindowsd.dll.embed.manifest">..\..\..\..\plug
ins\platforms\qwindowsd.dll_manifest.rc
        if not exist ..\..\..\..\plugins\platforms\qwindowsd.dll del ..\..\..\..
\plugins\platforms\qwindowsd.dll.embed.manifest>NUL 2>&1
        if exist ..\..\..\..\plugins\platforms\qwindowsd.dll.embed.manifest copy
 /Y ..\..\..\..\plugins\platforms\qwindowsd.dll.embed.manifest ..\..\..\..\plugi
ns\platforms\qwindowsd.dll_manifest.bak
        link /NOLOGO /DYNAMICBASE /NXCOMPAT /DEBUG /DLL /MANIFEST /MANIFESTFILE:
..\..\..\..\plugins\platforms\qwindowsd.dll.embed.manifest /OUT:..\..\..\..\plug
ins\platforms\qwindowsd.dll @C:\Users\tanya\AppData\Local\Temp\nmD410.tmp
   Creating library ..\..\..\..\plugins\platforms\qwindowsd.lib and object ..\
..\..\..\plugins\platforms\qwindowsd.exp

dlldata.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "_Accessible2_ProxyFileInfo"
dlldata.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "_AccessibleAction_ProxyFileInfo"
dlldata.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "_AccessibleApplication_ProxyFileInfo"
dlldata.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "_AccessibleComponent_ProxyFileInfo"
dlldata.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "_AccessibleEditableText_ProxyFileInfo"
dlldata.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "_AccessibleHyperlink_ProxyFileInfo"
dlldata.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "_AccessibleHypertext_ProxyFileInfo"
dlldata.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "_AccessibleImage_ProxyFileInfo"
dlldata.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "_AccessibleRelation_ProxyFileInfo"
dlldata.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "_AccessibleTable_ProxyFileInfo"
dlldata.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "_AccessibleTable2_ProxyFileInfo"
dlldata.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "_AccessibleTableCell_ProxyFileInfo"
dlldata.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "_AccessibleText_ProxyFileInfo"
dlldata.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "_AccessibleValue_ProxyFileInfo"
..\..\..\..\plugins\platforms\qwindowsd.dll : fatal error LNK1120: 14 unresolved externals
NMAKE : fatal error U1077: "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\BIN\link.EXE" : return code "0x460"
Stop.
NMAKE : fatal error U1077: "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\BIN\nmake.exe" : return code "0x2"
Stop.
NMAKE : fatal error U1077: cd : return code "0x2"
Stop.
NMAKE : fatal error U1077: cd : return code "0x2"
Stop.
NMAKE : fatal error U1077: cd : return code "0x2"
Stop.
NMAKE : fatal error U1077: cd : return code "0x2"
Stop.
NMAKE : fatal error U1077: cd : return code "0x2"
Stop.
```

Please help me!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15826893/building-qt5-with-visual-studio-2012-visual-studio-2013-and-integrating-with

Answer (score -1):

make sure you compile with:

```
 -no-accessibility -nomake demos -nomake examples
```

Comment: can you post your configure parameters.

Comment: I am running Windows7 with VS2012 and Qt 5.0.1

Comment: @user2030856 i was try empty parametrs and this parameters.

Answer (score -4):

Download 5.0.1 it compiles with out any errors.

Comment: have you doing a search about this issue? only windows 8 64 bit can work with VS 2012 and it's compiler.

Comment: I can't understand what you talk about? see this link: http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtdoc/supported-platforms.html , you talk about `breaking Qt rules`, `VS 2012 compiler` can't compile Qt projects under `Windows 7`, have your tried for compile any project in Qt with `MSVC 2012`? if `yes`, it must be `fails` according to `Qt rules`.