# Building Qt5 with Visual Studio 2012 / Visual Studio 2013, and integrating with the IDE

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-2013, qt5, directx-11

How do you get Qt5 to download and integrate with Visual Studio 2012? What are some of the problems you will encounter, and how do you solve those problems?

**UPDATE re. Visual Studio 2013**

Successes are reported with Visual Studio 2013 as well, and the notes are being maintained for VS 2013.

Also note that **the focus of the question** is strongly on just *building* Qt with Visual Studio.  There are also notes about integrating with the Visual Studio IDE

Comment: I'm also searching an answer. You may refer to http://qt-project.org/forums/viewthread/24896/ . I didn't try it. Please let us know if you succeed.

Comment: Note: This question/answer is linked from the Qt forum discussion linked in the above comment.

Comment: http://qt-project.org/downloads has Qt5.0.2 VS2012 x64 version now.

Comment: @user1899020 Great!  ... But, unfortunately, I'm required to build a 32-bit version right now in VS2012.

Comment: ... and now I need to build in VS2013 (before a pre-built is ready for this).  Do I sense a pattern?

Comment: Also see http://stackoverflow.com/a/14932316/368896

Comment: the tips how to compile Qt 5.5 with visual studio 2015 is below.

Answer (score 77, accepted):

This method is tested to work on Visual Studio 2013.  Pre-built binaries using Visual Studio 2012 and 2013 are available [here](http://www.qt.io/download-open-source/#), including OpenGL versions.

### **Step 1: The Setup**

1. Download and install RapidEE [here](http://www.rapidee.com/en/download#winxp). RapidEE is a windows environment variables editor. It is extremely useful for the rest of this process (and just in general).
2. Install the DirectX 11 SDK. It is now part of the Windows 8 SDK, so you first have to install the DirectX 10 SDK, which you can get [here](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=6812) (but see warning in next sentence). If you have the Visual C++ 2010 Redistributable Package installed, and you probably do (it is automatically installed along with VS 2010), follow the steps outlined [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/chuckw/archive/2011/12/09/known-issue-directx-sdk-june-2010-setup-and-the-s1023-error.aspx) to assist with the DirectX 10 installation. Once you have the DirectX 10 SDK installed, download and install the Windows 8 SDK [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/hh852363.aspx), which contains the DirectX *11* SDK.  *Yes, this is a pain, but unless you know you have the DirectX 11 SDK, the Qt build will fail*.
3. Install Python for Windows (I've heard 2.6+, working with 3.3) from [Python.org](http://www.python.org/download/) or [Anaconda Python](http://continuum.io/downloads#py34).
4. Install Perl for Windows from [ActiveState](http://www.activestate.com/activeperl/downloads).

---

### **Step 2: Gitting** (and building) **Qt5** (yes, [that means Git](http://www.syntevo.com/smartgithg/index.html))

1. Follow the [installation guide for Windows](http://qt-project.org/wiki/Building_Qt_5_from_Git) at the qt-project website.

   **Summary**

   To summarize the details from the above link and from the following notes (PLEASE SEE FOLLOWING NOTES if you have any errors; they might be answered):

   - Uninstall Avast (if you have this installed) to avoid build errors.  Yes, that literally means **uninstall** it.  Remove it 100% from your system.  *Deactivating* it **will not work**.  See detailed notes below.
   - **Note for the first steps**: DO NOT use SmartGit for the first `git` pull, below (unless you really know what you're doing), as SmartGit's defaults will pull *everything*, and that's not what you want.
   - [Git for Windows](http://msysgit.github.io/) must be installed.
   - Decide where you want to put the `Qt` installation, and `cd` to the directory that will contain the new installation from any Command Prompt window.  (Because the process is so fragile and error-prone, I personally put it directly in `C:`, but this is likely not necessary).
   - From the above directory, execute:

     **`git clone git://gitorious.org/qt/qt5.git qt5`**

     This is fast.  Once complete, you should be on the 'stable' branch, but you can always run `git checkout stable` after `cd`ing into the newly-created `qt5` directory, just to be sure. Using `git checkout 5.4.1` is confirmed to work with VS2013 64-bit.
   - **Close out of your current command prompt window** (if it's not a Visual Studio command prompt window) before proceeding to the next step.  This is to make sure you're using the Visual Studio command prompt window in the next steps.
   - Next run the 32-bit (x86) or 64-bit VS Tools command prompt (depending on whether you're building Qt5 as 32- or 64-bit).  To access this, you must find it through the Start menu - go to `Program Files` -> `[Microsoft] Visual Studio 2012/2013` -> `Visual Studio Tools`, and you'll see it in there with a funny name; the name should include the phrase `Native Tools`; the 32-bit version will have `x86` in the name and the 64-bit version will have `x64` in the name.
   - `cd` into the newly-created `qt5` directory from the step above.
   - From within the Visual Studio command prompt, the remainder of the Qt submodules must be downloaded:

     **`perl ./init-repository --no-webkit`**

     It takes kind of a while to execute this step, because it has to download a lot, but it's not too terrible on a decent connection.
   - Then download any remaining OPTIONAL submodules that `init-repository` does not download - SmartGit works well only starting at this stage (see comments below).
   - Once the download of Qt is complete, the following command prepares the build environment (it should also be executed using the [32|64] VS Native Tools Command Prompt):

     **`configure -developer-build -opensource -confirm-license -mp -nomake examples -nomake tests -debug-and-release -c++11 -no-warnings-are-errors -platform win32-msvc2012`**.

     Notes on this command line: the `c++11` option might not be necessary with the VS2012 compiler, but works with VS2013; the `-no-warnings-are-errors` is necessary in case you get errors on a 64-bit automatic build of ANGLE; `-platform` is automatically set to `win32-msvc2012`, so by default the 32-bit build of Qt is used, and -platform probably does not need to be supplied at the command line (EVEN if you have previous versions of VS installed). For VS2013, use `-platform win32-msvc2013`.

     It takes a few minutes to execute this step, but it's not so bad.
   - Finally, the command to actually build Qt on the system (also run within the VS Native Tools Command Prompt) is simply:

     **`nmake`**

     *Expect to wait hours for the build to complete.*  If you specified an output folder with `-prefix` (see notes below), then use `nmake install`, otherwise that's it.

---

**NOTES:**

**General Notes**

In case you're confused from the above-linked documentation, just an FYI that the ANGLE library will be used (by default) instead of OpenGL, and that's why you had to install DirectX 11, above.

Make sure that you [use the VS Native Tools Command Prompt](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229859.aspx) to run all commands from the above link (that is, `perl .\init-repository --no-webkit`, `configure`, and `nmake`).  You will use the [32|64] bit command prompt (`x86` or `x64`), depending on whether you are building Qt as 32-bit or 64-bit. If you install perl with the Command Prompt open (make sure it is in the `PATH`), you will need to restart the Command Prompt for perl to be recognized as a command.

When running "init-repository" (from the steps in the above link), it's not clear from the documentation, but you must execute this via `perl`; i.e. `perl ./init-repository --no-webkit`.  The `configure` and `nmake` commands, however, are called directly.

One very useful option to pass to `configure` is `-mp`, which causes Qt to build on multiple cores in parallel, significantly speeding up the (long) build time.

To specify an output folder add the `-prefix [outfolder]` to the `configure` command.  For example, use `-prefix %CD%\output\x64\vc12` would be a suitable output (sub)folder for a 64-bit Visual Studio 2013 (12.0) build.

---

**Unicode Support (ICU)**

If you want Unicode support (via [ICU](http://site.icu-project.org/download)), pay special attention to the instructions noted within the link above.  In summary, ICU must be built from scratch in VS 2012, as the only prebuilt ICU binaries for Windows are for VS 2010.  Building in VS 2012 is painless - simply locate the ICU solution (.sln) in <icuroot>\icu\source\allinone, and build in both Debug and Release mode (either in 32-bit or 64-bit mode, depending on which mode you're building Qt in - DO NOT build in the other bitness, because ICU will overwrite the output folder with the binaries).  (The Qt build process will properly locate the debug vs. release build of ICU.)  It should build without errors.  Then, add the path to <icuroot>\lib as a string entry in a (probably) NEW Windows environment variable called "LIB" (you can use Rapid EE for this; make LIB an "expandable string" in RapidEE even though there's only 1 entry), and also add the path to <icuroot>\include as a string entry in a (probably) NEW Windows environment variable called "INCLUDE". (Note: Adding these paths to the PATH variable will not work.)  After Qt is built, you can remove all of these entries you've just added.  Also, do **add the runtime path to the ICU dll's (<icuroot>\bin) to the environment's PATH variable, or the Qt build process (specifically, when `uic.exe` runs) will give a [deceptive and misleading error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15953310/what-does-set-path-path-mean-in-a-windows-shell-script-and-how-can)**.  Finally, on the `configure` command line (below), be sure to add `-icu` as an additional command-line parameter.

**ICU Failure**:

Currently, there seems to be a bug building Qt5 with the VS2012 compiler WHEN ICU IS ENABLED.  Specifically, `qtbase\src\corelib\codecs\qtextcodec.cpp` Line 688 (Qt5 v5.02) fails to return a codec for codec name "US-ASCII" (the codec is NULL), causing "lrelease.exe" to crash when trying to dereference the codec later (I have lost track of that file/line number, but it is an obvious dereference of the NULL `codec` variable).  Unfortunately, this means that to my knowledge, **WebKit cannot be built with (at least the) 32-bit build of Qt5 with the VS2012 compiler**, because WebKit requires ICU.

*If anyone is able to build Qt5 with the VS2012 compiler with ICU enabled, please update this Wiki saying so.*

**ICU Clarification**:

If you have ICU in your path, Qt will automatically built it. In other words, the flag "`-icu`" is there implicitly. However, this causes an error with "lrelease.exe" as mentioned above. So the way around this would be to add the flag, -no-icu to the configure command

---

**Additional Submodules**

If you want submodules *in addition* to the default submodules, you can use SmartGit (or command line) *after* you complete the `init-repository` command.  SmartGit is perhaps easiest, because you do not need to copy the path to the command line, but can use the user interface directly.

***WARNING:* DO NOT DOWNLOAD THE OPTIONAL `qlalr` SUBMODULE**, as it will not build in combination with the overall Qt build, and is not necessary for users of Qt, but is only used for internal Qt development.

*WARNING:* A shell command line, followed by `perl .\init-repository --no-webkit`, must be used (NOT SmartGit); these steps will properly only download the default Qt submodules.  You must **not** use SmartGit to clone and download the Git files from `git://gitorious.org/qt/qt5.git` because SmartGit does not currently handle the submodules properly.  Instead, open a standard Windows shell command prompt (using any command-prompt application, not necessarily the VS Tools command prompt), and (assuming Git is properly installed on the system; a SmartGit installation might or might not do this automatically; if it does not, go to [Git for Windows](http://msysgit.github.io/) and install directly) type `git clone git://gitorious.org/qt/qt5.git` directly from the command line; perhaps follow that with `git checkout stable` (I'm not sure if this branch is checked out by default); then follow that with the command line `perl .\init-repository --no-webkit` to pull down the DEFAULT repositories (except WebKit, which requires ICU and ICU seemingly cannot be built in 32-bit Qt5 with VS2012; see comments).

The steps for downloading all necessary Qt source files therefore are: 
  1. Use a Windows command line to execute the initial `git clone git://gitorious.org/qt/qt5.git`; 
  2. Execute `perl .\init-repository --no-webkit` from within a VS Tools 2012 Command Prompt; and then optionally 
  3. Use SmartGit (from above link) (or equivalent) to "open an existing project" (choose the Qt5 root folder) and do a Pull from within SmartGit to download any non-default repositories (but do not download `qlalr`).  That's it; you have all necessary and optional Qt files (including submodules) on your system.

*If anybody discovers other optional submodules that fail to build and/or are for internal use only (besides `qlalr`), please update this Wiki to specify them.*

In general, the default submodules obtained via `perl .\init-repository --no-webkit` are sufficient.  If you know, or later find out, that you other (non-default) modules, you can always add them later.

---

**General Problems**

If at some point you get the error saying that the command "python" (or anything similar) is not recognized, just check that the folder containing `python.exe` (or the appropriate `.exe`) is part of the path variable. If it is not, add it (use RapidEE as noted above for convenience) and try what you were doing again. If it is there, make sure you have restarted your command prompt AFTER the addition of the command to the path.

Two other path-related issues are important to note (quoted from the documentation associated with the link above): "*Make sure the perl executable is found in the path before the perl executable provided by msysgit, since the latter is outdated*"; and "*You might not be able to build if sh.exe is in your PATH (for example due to a git or msys installation). Such an error is indicated by qt5-srcqtbasebinqmake.exe: command not found and alike. In this case, make sure that sh.exe is not in your path. You will have to re-configure if your installation is already configured.*"

During the process, you may encounter an error using `nmake` on a file. If you do, just go into that directory and force build the problem file. Then begin the `nmake` process on Qt5 again.

---

**Specific Problems**

*WARNING:* You may need to disable antivirus software **AND SANDBOXING** during the Qt `nmake` process (and, to be safe, throughout this entire process).  Internally, Qt executes a number of executables that antivirus programs can interfere with (sometimes silently).  In particular, if you have any sandboxing software, be SURE to disable sandboxing.

*WARNING:* **AVAST!** Sandbox users: Avast Sandbox has a bug in which even when you disable Avast's auto-sandbox, the sandbox will NOT turn off and it will silently sandbox all resource files automatically created by Qt's `rcc` program during Qt's build process.  The Qt build ALWAYS fails for any user who has installed the Avast autosandbox feature, EVEN WITH AUTO-SANDBOXING TURNED OFF.  THE ONLY WAY TO OVERCOME THIS ISSUE IS TO COMPLETELY UNINSTALL AVAST! FROM YOUR SYSTEM before building Qt.  You can reinstall Avast! after the Qt build is complete.

---

The compilation of Qt5 can take a long time (hours, even with the -mp multithreading option). Patience.

---

### **Step 3: Integrating Qt5 with Visual Studio 2012**

1. Download and install the Visual Studio [Qt5 addin](http://www.qt.io/download-open-source/#section-7). It is in the "Other Downloads" section near the bottom of the page, and will not work with Visual Studio Express.
2. Open Visual Studio 2012, and go to `Qt Options` (It's under "Qt5" on the top menu bar).
3. In the Qt Versions tab, check to see if Qt5 is already there. If it is not, click add, choose a version name (probably a name such as 5.x.x), and navigate to the folder containing `qmake.exe` (usually `C:\Qt\qt5\qtbase`).
4. Exit the Qt Options dialog.
5. Create a new Visual Studio Project.  When you see the New Project dialog, you should see the `Qt5 Projects` Template option.
6. Once you have your new Qt Project, right click on it and select "Convert to QMake generated project". Build the project, then right click on it again and select "Convert project to Qt Add-in project". Build again, then run. You should now have a working Qt Project.

---

### **Add Qt5 to an existing Visual Studio 2012 VC++ project**

*This section may or may not work for you. If you run into problems or have additional/better solutions, please leave a comment or edit the appropriate step.*

1. Right-click on your project in VS, and choose "unload project". Right click on the project again, and select "edit [project name].vcxproj". This opens the project file so you can add Qt5 to it.
2. Go down to the Global PropertyGroup, and add or change the `<Keyword>` to Qt4VSv1.0.
3. Reload the project, then right-click and select "Convert project to Qt Add-in project"
4. Wait for the conversion to finish (it does not take more than a couple seconds), then choose `Qt5>Project Settings`. Go to the Modules tab, and check the modules you would like your project to rely on (the basic ones are `Core`, `Widgets`, and `GUI`).
5. Following the steps [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/73f9s62w.aspx), add the directory `$(QTDIR)\include`.

   ---

   **NOTES:**

   If at any time you are including `windows.h`, you need to `#define NOMINMAX` *before* doing so to prevent conflict with `qdatetime.h`.

   Once the above steps are done, you can make your project usable by Qt Creator by selecting `Qt5>Create basic .pro file`.

---

**ENDING NOTES:** If you have a question related to the information contained in this guide, please post it as a new question (not an answer here), and the answer or a link to the answer may get added.

Comment: Exceedingly awesome.  (I found this from the link you posted on the Qt forums).  I hope that this link gets publicity on the Qt site and further worked on.  I am about to embark on this starting with a fresh install of VS 2012 (and VS 2010 SP1).  I will append anything that might prove a useful addition.

Comment: @DanNissenbaum  I hope this helps. Make sure to update with problems you ran into.

Comment: I cannot get past `missing .rcc\debug_shared\qrc_mimetype.cpp`.  After receiving this same error last night, today I started from scratch by deleting my entire Qt folder and re-downloading Qt, followed by `init-repository`, and when that completed (reporting a handful of "permission denied" errors) I followed up by opening the Git project in SmartGit, noticed some empty submodules, and did a `pull` via SmartGit (including submodules), which reported success and populated all submodules. Unfortunately, `nmake` failed at exactly the same place - the `missing qrc_mimetypes.cpp`.  Any suggestions?

Comment: My above comment is now a question on StackOverflow; here is the link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15932767/missing-qrc-mimetypes-cpp-while-attempting-to-build-qt

Comment: Sadly, the above instructions simply do not work.  It is not possible to build Qt on Windows 7 using the above instructions, or any obvious variation of the instructions.  I will search for a way to build Qt that works, and then adjust the above Wiki entry if and when I am able to do so.

Comment: I discovered the problem related to my previous comment.  There is a bug with Avast! antivirus's sandbox, such that Avast! must be completely uninstalled from the operating system in order for Qt to build, because the Avast! auto-sandbox feature will not turn off even when it is set to "disabled", but instead enters "silent" sandbox mode; Avast! was taking the output of Qt's `rcc` command and removing these files (silently, without warning) from the system, causing the Qt build to fail.  The only way to turn off Avast! completely is to uninstall it.  I have modified the Wiki to discuss this.

Comment: My next show-stopping obstacle preventing Qt5 from building is now described in another StackOverflow posting: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15953310/what-does-set-path-path-mean-in-a-windows-shell-script-and-how-can

Comment: The above issue is resolved: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15955621/368896.  I have integrated this information into the wiki.

Comment: Wow. That is quite the obscure catch. Nice job.

Comment: The next in the long string of Qt5 build show-stopping obstacles is this: http://www.qtcentre.org/threads/54059-Failed-on-building-qlalr-submodule-when-compiling-QT5-for-VS2012.  I am having the exact problem described in that link.  I will append as soon as I have it resolved.

Comment: The resolution is that `qlalr` is not intended to be downloaded and built by users of Qt; it is for internal use only.  It only builds by itself; not in the context of a full Qt build.  I have updated the Wiki.

Comment: The next show-stopping obstacle is that `lrelease.exe` crashes, even when building only the default set of modules.  As soon as I resolve this issue, I will post.

Comment: The above issue is an ICU issue: When ICU is enabled, `qtbase\src\corelib\codecs\qtextcodec.cpp` Line 688 fails to return a codec for codec name `US-ASCII` ... causing `lrelease.exe` to crash when trying to dereference the codec later.  I am (painfully) rebuilding without ICU.

Comment: I have updated the Wiki to indicate that it seems to be impossible to include ICU support in a VS2012 build of Qt5.

Comment: I have posted a question regarding this issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15975608/icu-support-in-a-32-bit-build-of-qt5-with-the-vs2012-compiler-causes-qt5-build-f

Comment: I successfully built a 64-bit version just following the basic steps this wiki had.

Comment: I've worked through all the steps and now have a working Qt5 project in VS 2012.

Comment: Very helpful even for Visual Studio 2010!

Comment: Has anyone reported the bug to Avast? Is there a link to the bug report?

Comment: @jon I reported the bug to Avast! in a detailed email.  I received a form letter response only.

Comment: Well then, screw them. I need an AV that is compatible with software development tools and whose developers respond to bug reports. Avast has lost another user.

Comment: Now, there is also a prebuilt version of Qt 5.2 for VS2012 available at http://qt-project.org/downloads that you can use, if there is no special need to build Qt on your own.

Comment: This is a great guide! This worked for me with VS2013. However, with regards to ICU support, if you have ICU in your path, you should add the -no-icu option when configuring, otherwise it will cause an error with lrelease.exe like you mentioned. I think this statement, "Finally, on the configure command line (below), be sure to add -icu as an additional command-line parameter" is incorrect (since no-one has got it to work so far, to my knowledge. And also since icu is automatically added to Qt if it finds it in your path. Also, the archived source code on the qt downloads page works fine too

Comment: @user929404 Any way you could add those comments into the (community wiki) answer?  That'd be great!

Comment: @DanNissenbaum I have already, after I realised that it was a wiki

Comment: I am unable to complete the build. There is no bin folder like the previous builds usually. Missing ScriptEngine too. Desperately searching for QT5.4.0-openGL-OpenSSL x64 VS2012

Comment: @VivianLobo I am not sure what part of the process failed for you. If you find a solution, please add the problem+solution to the wiki.

Answer (score 10):

I successfully managed to integrate Qt 5.0.2 with Visual Studio 2012 on Windows 7 based on the excellent wiki above and on [this qt-project link](http://qt-project.org/wiki/Building_Qt_5_from_Git) as well. Since I made some of the steps on a slightly different way, I thought it would be valid to post it in here:

The sequence below should be executed in the exact given order:

0 - Uninstall Avast (if you have this installed) to avoid build errors. Due to an Avast bug, deactivating it will not work;

1 - Install Git (>= 1.6.x);

2 - Install Python (>=2.6.x). [python.org];

3 - Install Perl (>=5.14). [activestate.com];

4 - Install Ruby. [rubyinstaller.org];

5 - Open the Windows 7 Command Prompt (don't use VS2012 Developer Command Prompt by now);

6 - Choose any directory you want for qt5, regarding that **NO SPACES ARE ALLOWED** for the chosen path. I decided to use the path "C:\qt5";

7 - Back to Windows 7 Command Prompt (in my case, prompting "C:\qt5>") type:

```
git clone git://gitorious.org/qt/qt5.git qt5
```

8 - Checkout the stable version:

```
cd qt5
git checkout stable
```

9 - You'll probably receive a message confirming that this version is already stable. Close the Command Prompt;

10 - Open Visual Studio's Developers Console *(All Programs > Visual Studio 2012 > Visual Studio Tools > Developer Command Prompt for VS2012)* and change the current directory to the one you have chosen("C:\qt5" in my example);

11 - Download Qt submodules, ignoring webkit (common source of build errors...):

```
perl .\init-repository --no-webkit
```

12 - Now enter this huge command to configure your build properly:

```
configure -developer-build -opensource -nomake examples -nomake tests -nomake demos -debug-and-release -c++11 -mp -nomake webkit -confirm-license
```

13 - Next, ensure that the module **qlalr** will **NOT** be built. To do this, open Windows Explorer and navigate to your chosen Qt directory ("*C:\qt5*" in my example) and check if the folder *qlalr* exists. If so, delete it;

14 - Time to build... Possible build errors would come from secondary modules (such as webkit), which don't affect the main Qt functionality (webkit itself should not be a problem since we've previously set the configuration not to build it). We can then ignore them and also keep the build running on independent modules:

```
nmake /I /K
```

15 - To conclude integration, follow the step 3 of the community wiki above("Step 3: Integrating Qt5 with Visual Studio 2012").

Answer (score 6):

Just want to mention that there is a prebuilt version of Qt 5.2 for Visual Studio 2012 available at http://qt-project.org/downloads. So if you don't have a special interest in building Qt 5 from sources you can use the prebuild binaries, too.

There are also several precompiled (x64) binaries for different compiler versions available at the [Tver-Soft website](http://www.tver-soft.org/).

Comment: So I don't need to download anything else with it like the `qt` installer

Answer (score 4):

I was finally able to compile QT 5.1 (git) with QWebKit on Windows 8 x64 using Visual Studio 2012 and figured I'd share my experience with those that had problems as well.

Did step 1 and 2 as stated in the above post. I tried to do step 3 but SmartGit pulled a bunch of extra projects that wouldn't compile with Qt5. I was able to solve most of the problems by cloning from a different fork (e.g. https://qt.gitorious.org/qt/qt3d/), but this became too tedious to do for every extra module, so I decided against compiling any of them.

The post at [ICU support in a 32-bit build of Qt5 with the VS2012 compiler causes Qt5 build failure; Webkit is also therefore unbuildable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15975608/icu-support-in-a-32-bit-build-of-qt5-with-the-vs2012-compiler-causes-qt5-build-f) told me how to fix the ICU problem.

Download the source code at http://download.icu-project.org/files/icu4c/51.2/icu4c-51_2-src.zip and add the line

```
#define U_CHARSET_IS_UTF8 1
```

to the file %ICU%\source\common\unicode\platform.h , where %ICU% is the path to the ICU source code.

Open %ICU%\source\allinone\allinone.sln file in Visual Studio 2012 and compile. Add %ICU%\bin to your path

```
set PATH=%ICU%\bin64;%PATH%
```

Then I ran the following command in the QT root directory

```
configure -platform win32-msvc2012 -opengl desktop -opensource -debug-and-release -I %ICU%\include -L %ICU%\icu\lib64 -mp -qt-freetype -icu
```

At this point I started to suspect that no one tried to do what I was doing, because nmake started to complain about unexpected lines in the makefiles (all of which had the extension DerivedSources, e.g. Makefile.JavaScriptCore.DerivedSources and Makefile.WebCore.DerivedSources))

```
(set PATH=<stuff>;%PATH%) && ....
```

do the set PATH manually before running nmake and delete the characters up to and including && e.g.

```
 (set PATH=<stuff>;%PATH%) && perl -ne "print $1" css\CSSPropertyNames.in ...
```

Becomes

```
perl -ne "print $1" css\CSSPropertyNames.in ...
```

Finally, one of these files will try to call win_flex.exe (or win-flex.exe) instead of flex. I changed it to flex.exe and everything finally compiled (Had to change it twice, because I think the file got regenerated).

Brief experience with a program that uses QWebKit and linked against this build leads me to believe everything is fine.

--Update--

Just to be complete. According to [What does (set PATH=...;%PATH:)=^)%) mean in a Windows shell script, and how can I overcome failure of this line in the context of a Qt5 nmake build?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15953310/what-does-set-path-path-mean-in-a-windows-shell-script-and-how-can?lq=1) (which points to http://qt-project.org/forums/viewthread/20605) most of the Makefile problems should be solvable by using jsom instead of nmake (although I still wonder about win-flex.exe)

Comment: ...I think (but am not positive) a big part of your problem was using SmartGet. You're not supposed to use that for the initial pull...

Comment: SmartGit blindly pulls ALL internal modules, even those that should not be included.  Attempting to build them will cause build errors.  It's important to pull *only* the necessary modules, and no more, for the initial build step.

Answer (score 2):

### compile Qt 5.5 with visual studio 2015:

1- Modify configure.bat in qtbase directory so it can generate configure.exe (just the first 18 lines)

```
  @echo off
set QTSRC=%~dp0
set QTDIR=%CD%
rem if not exist %QTSRC%.gitignore goto sconf
echo Please wait while bootstrapping configure ...
 
for %%C in (cl.exe icl.exe g++.exe perl.exe) do set %%C=%%~$PATH:C
 
rem if "%perl.exe%" == "" (
rem    echo Perl not found in PATH. Aborting. >&2
rem    exit /b 1
rem )
if not exist mkspecs (
    md mkspecs
    if errorlevel 1 goto exit
)
rem perl %QTSRC%bin\syncqt.pl -minimal -module QtCore -outdir "%QTDIR%" %QTSRC%
rem if errorlevel 1 goto exit
```

2- `configure -opensource -confirm-license -mp -nomake examples -nomake tests -release -c++11 -no-warnings-are-errors -platform win32-msvc2015 -no-ltcg`

3- `nmake`

Comment: I did not have to edit configure.bat for Qt to build, but I could not build all of Qt, namely QtWebEngine.