# What does (set PATH=...;%PATH:)=^)%) mean in a Windows shell script, and how can I overcome failure of this line in the context of a Qt5 nmake build?

Tags: qt, shell, windows-7, makefile, qt5

In the context of an [obstacle-ridden process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15932767/missing-qrc-mimetypes-cpp-while-attempting-to-build-qt-on-windows-7-32-bit-bu) of attempting to [build Qt5 (32-bit) with VS 2012](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15893226/368896), I have run into yet another build error.

It is:

> (set PATH=C:\Users\daniel347x\Desktop\Backup\__Dan_Root\qt5\qtbase\lib;%PATH:)=^)%) &
> C:\Users\daniel347x\Desktop\Backup__Dan_Root\qt5\qtbase\bin\uic.exe
> dialogs\qfiledialog.ui -o ui_qfiledialog.h
>
> NMAKE : fatal error U1077:
> '(set' : return code '0xc0000135'
>
> Stop.

I cannot find anything relevant about the `(set PATH=...;%PATH:)=^)%)` failure issue (returning error code `0xc0000135`) when I perform a detailed Google/StackOverflow search.

Note that `nmake` proceeds for a long time (more than 1 hour) happily switching directories, running intermediate .exe's, and both compiling and linking code files.

I am running `nmake` (as well as having run `configure`) in the 32-bit Visual Studio 2012 Tools command prompt; and as far as I know, all of my `path` variables are properly set (they include the paths to 32-bit Perl and to 32-bit Python, although I don't think that is relevant here).

I have restarted my computer, and I ran the VS 2012 Tools Command Prompt with Administrator privileges (in case it is a permissions error), attempting to run `nmake`, and the same error occurs.

I then attempted to try to figure out what the error actually is.  At that point, I became stumped by the syntax of this command-line statement that is apparently being executed within a Makefile-triggered shell script:

```
(set PATH=...;%PATH:)=^)%)
                   ^^^^^^ // What do the symbols :)=^)% mean?
```

I do not understand the symbols **:)=^)%** in the context of this script.

Can somebody tell me what these symbols mean in the context of a Windows shell script (that is being executed in the context of an `nmake` Makefile (building 32-bit Qt5 with VS 2012))?

As an added optional question, what can I do to overcome this error and continue to build Qt5 without this error blocking progress?

Comment: I believe those are string manipulations on the path variable, but I'm not sure what they are doing specifically.

Comment: If the goal is just to prepend a new directory onto the front of the path and no string manipulations are needed, then the :>=^)% could be replaced with just the %   resulting in (set PATH=...;%PATH%)

Comment: I hesitate to modify the Qt makefile scripts, at least without knowing what the string manipulation is actually doing.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `(set PATH=...;%PATH:)=^)%)` is a string substitution. Look up 'environment variable substitution' in the `help set` command output for more information.

The script prepends the PATH variable, but during the substitution it escapes the right parens so the whole line is correctly formatted. For example, the %PATH% might contain a substring "Program Files (x86)" that will break the `set` syntax upon expansion. The `^` symbol before the paren is just a batch escaping symbol.

Second, the `(...) & ...` is a [grouping operator](http://judago.webs.com/batchoperators.htm#841124554) that allows multiple commands to be written on the same line. Why the script author decided to place those two commands on the same line is unknown to me, but it has definitely helped to obscure the error.

Third, though NMAKE reports an error for the '(set' command, quick checking proved that the return code (%ERRORLEVEL%) is set by the last command of the group, so there is no use of googling the `0xc0000135` error for the SET and NMAKE commands.

The actual source of the error is the 'uic.exe', that is located in:

```
C:\Users\daniel347x\Desktop\Backup__Dan_Root\qt5\qtbase\bin\uic.exe
```

Regarding the error, 0xc0000135 - this is `The application failed to initialize properly` error. My guess is either that the 'uic.exe' was built with the incompatible toolchain/SDK, or requires some missing dlls.

P.S. An alternative solution: the similar problem [has been solved](http://qt-project.org/forums/viewthread/20605) by using jom instead of nmake.

Comment: ...Which immediately led me to investigate `uic.exe` using Dependency Walker, which revealed that `icu` DLL's were missing, which made it obvious that though I had added the ICU `include` and `lib` paths, I had not added the runtime path containing the ICU DLL's, and the problem is resolved.  Indeed, the shell script system did a very poor job of identifying the source of the error.

Comment: @DanNissenbaum you should put or request to add your comment as a possible thing to check to solve this problem. It really saved me a lot of time.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. I decided to add it to the PATH path to the libraries icu.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue compiling `Qt5.3` in `Win8`.  The solution is to make sure you include the `ICU` and `openSSL` 32-bin binaries location in the PATH variable.  If you don't `uic.exe` doesn't work properly

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, in my case I used a bad compiled ICU ( compiled with VS2012 ) trying to use icu with VS2008, I solve it compiling ICU with VS2008 and using these compiled version of ICU on my VS2008 project.