# How to build Qt 5.5 QtWebEngine on Windows & MSVC 2015

Tags: qt, build, visual-studio-2015, qt5, qtwebengine

Has anyone successfully built Qt's WebEngine / QtWebEngine / QWebEngine on Windows using Microsoft Visual Studio C++ 2015?

What prerequisites are necessary?

I managed to build Qt itself, but QtWebEngine was skipped, so I tried `nmake module-qtwebengine` which fails for several reasons.

Comment: Let me point you to https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic:
_"if your question generally covers… software tools commonly used by programmers; and is a practical, answerable problem that is unique to software development … then you’re in the right place to ask your question!"_ I'd dare say Qt is at least sometimes used by programmers, and that this is a practical question.

Comment: @SaZ, I could also ask more directly: How did **you** get PyQt 5 to work with QtWebEngine under Windows, as you're obviously a Qt / PyQt guru? Would that be more on-topic?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is only a partial answer as of now intended to give anyone interested some pointers in the right direction.

First, Qt 5.5.0 does *not* support Microsoft Visual C++ 2015 *at all*.

That said, we can patch `qtwebengine\tools\qmake\mkspecs\features\functions.prf` and change the few occurrences of `win32-msvc2013` to `win32-msvc2015` to ignore the error that we are not using MSVC 2013.

You need Python 2.x in your path for building. Python 3 will not work.

Open a Visual Studio 2015 Command Prompt and change to your Qt source directory root.

To utilize multiple cores on your machine, do `set CL=/MP`.

Run `configure -release -confirm-license -nomake examples -opensource`.
Note that `-debug` may fail.

Run `nmake module-qtwebengine`.

Now, when we try to build it, it will probably fail because it cannot find a ninja -- yet another build tool to complicate things, and included in the Qt source. You can either try to build it, or you get a [binary for Windows from GitHub](https://github.com/martine/ninja/releases) and save `ninja.exe` as `qtwebengine\src\3rdparty\ninja\ninja.exe`.

Looks like I am not the only one having problems... and one reason seems to be Chromium itself, and that looks like unfinished work.

> > does anybody now if and when QtWebEngine will build with VS1025?
>
> When Chromium starts supporting building with VS2015. So far it doesn't looks 
>   like it will be in 5.6

http://lists.qt-project.org/pipermail/development/2015-July/022723.html

**HERE BE DRAGONS**

*to be continued...*

Comment: Qt 5.5 aleady has `win32-msvc2015` in mkspecs.

Comment: So you apparently did not try to build it.

Comment: I just managed to compile Qt 5.5 with Visual Studio 2015 [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15826893/building-qt5-with-visual-studio-2012-visual-studio-2013-and-integrating-with/32741509#32741509)

Comment: @hatranpro I managed to compile Qt as well with MSVC 2015, however it did not build QtWebEngine. Did yours build?

Comment: @Archimedix No, it did not compiled, perhaps you should specify it in the configure.

Comment: Seems default build of `QtWebEngine` not support play `mp3` files. What flag should be added to support it?